# Regex replace and append string

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, append

I managed to delete every '-xx' in a string (Example 1).
I would like your help to make examples 2 and 3 to work.

```js
function myFunction() {
    var str1 = 'foot zi-cnn-xx vi-sky-xx test vi-axn-xx red';
    var str2 = 'foot zi-cnn vi-sky test vi-axn red';
    
    // Example 1
    // remove every '-xx'
    var res1 = str1.replace(/-xx/g, '');
    document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = res1;
    
    // Example 2
    // delete every '-xx' from str1 substring that starts with 'vi'
    // expected: 'foot zi-cnn-xx vi-sky test vi-axn red';
    
    // Example 3
    // add '-xx' to str2, to every substring that starts with 'vi'
    // expected: 'foot zi-cnn vi-sky-xx test vi-axn-xx red';

}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Test this</button>

<p id="demo1"></p>
<p id="demo2"></p>
<p id="demo3"></p>
```

Comment: Do you have any code that you've tried to write to accomplish the goals in those examples? What part are you having trouble with? It's not appropriate to just list your requirements and ask someone to provide you the entire implementation.

Comment: Hint: use a capture group

Comment: Thanks for the tip Barmar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace `vi-([-\w]+)-xx` to `vi-$1` for case 2
and `vi-([-\w]+)` to `vi-$1-xx` for case 3.

Snippet:

```js
function myFunction() {
    var str1 = 'foot zi-cnn-xx vi-sky-xx test vi-axn-xx red';
    var str2 = 'foot zi-cnn vi-sky test vi-axn red';
    
    // Example 1
    // remove every '-xx'
    var res1 = str1.replace(/-xx/g, '');
    document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = res1;
    
    // Example 2
    // delete every '-xx' from str1 substring that starts with 'vi'
    // expected: 'foot zi-cnn-xx vi-sky test vi-axn red';
    var res2 = str1.replace(/vi-([-\w]+)-xx/g, "vi-$1");
    document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = res2;
    
    // Example 3
    // add '-xx' to str2, to every substring that starts with 'vi'
    // expected: 'foot zi-cnn vi-sky-xx test vi-axn-xx red';
    var res3 = str2.replace(/vi-([-\w]+)/g, "vi-$1-xx");
    document.getElementById("demo3").innerHTML = res3;

}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Test this</button>

<p id="demo1"></p>
<p id="demo2"></p>
<p id="demo3"></p>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I  'll in youtube for some tutorials about regex.

Comment: Thanks doc!! Basically is use groups ( ) and $1 to refer the matched string